# Duplicate Reminder notifications on some recurring reminders

Tags: notifications, reminders

I've had this issue ever since the Reminders upgrade a few years ago.  I forget which iOS/macOS version it was, but ever since the upgrade, there are certain recurring reminder notifications that behave in the following way:

1. Reminder notification pops up (either on iOS or macOS)
2. I either mark the reminder as complete, clear it, or tell it to remind me again later
3. The reminder notification goes away
4. The same reminder notification immediately reappears
5. I repeat what I did in step 2 and the notification goes away in the expected manner

The next time the reminder notification shows up again, whether it's because I told it to remind me in an hour or it's because of the prescribed recurrence, the same exact thing happens.

With some recurring reminders, this doesn't happen.  I have a number of recurring reminders and I would say that the majority of them behave this way.  And I know that it's not just reminder recurrences that predate the upgrade.  This happens to new recurring reminders too.  I haven't worked out a predictable pattern.

I have tried:

1. Deleting and recreating the reminders (no effect)
2. Logging out and back into iCloud
3. Turning off reminders synch and turning it back on
4. Updating to the latest iOS/macOS (multiple times over the past few years)

I have poked around in the sqlite database, and it looks like there may exist duplicate entries for these reminders (not due to the recurrence - Reminders creates a new record for every recurrence) that have different UIDs.  But those duplicates do not appear as separate records in the Reminders app.

I've done quite a bit of development writing reminders scripts for automation triggers, so I'm fairly knowledgeable about the SQLite structure.  I don't know enough to feel confident executing any updates or deletes, so I only ever execute selects, but I feel like some deletes might be a solution if I knew it wouldn't create any orphaned relations.

Though even if I could figure out the deletes, that's not going to prevent this from happening to new recurring reminders.  Has anyone had this problem before and figured out how to solve and prevent these duplicate notifications?